# For each results- Mysql - JSON

Tags: php, json

How i separate the first result of for each loop and remaining. I have 2 divs, i want first result to be displayed there and rest on another div.

Also is there any way that i can get json decode without for each loop, i want to display result based on for each values from database, and querying database in for each loop is not recommended.

Here is my code, What i want

```
<div class="FirstDiv">
Result1
</div>

<div class="RemDiv">
Remaining result from for each loop
</div>
```

Here is full code

```
$data = json_decode($response->raw_body, true);
$i = 0;
foreach($data['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids'] as $value) {
    if (++$i == 6)
        break;

    $check = "SELECT fullname FROM test_celebrities WHERE shortname = '$value[prediction]'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($rs)==1) //uid found in the table
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
        $fullname= $row['fullname'];
    }

    echo 'Celebrity Name: ' . $fullname . '<br/>';
    echo 'Similar: ' . $value['confidence']*100 .'%'. '<br/><br/>';
    echo "<img src='actors/$value[prediction].jpg'>";
    echo "<hr/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($response->raw_body, true);
$i = 0;

echo '<div class="FirstDiv">'; // add this line here
foreach( $data['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids'] as $value ) {
    if (++$i == 6) break;

    $check = "SELECT fullname FROM test_celebrities WHERE shortname = '$value[prediction]'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);

    if ( mysqli_num_rows($rs) == 1 ) { //uid found in the table
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
        $fullname= $row['fullname'];
    }

    // Echo celebrity information: 
    echo 'Celebrity Name: ' . $fullname . '<br/>';
    echo 'Similar: ' . $value['confidence']*100 .'%'. '<br/><br/>';
    echo "<img src='actors/$value[prediction].jpg'>";
    echo "<hr/>";

    if ($i==1) { echo '</div><div class="RemDiv">'; }; // add this line here
}
echo '</div>'; // close the last tag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$predictions=array();
foreach($data['photos'][0]['tags'][0]['uids'] as $value) {
   $predictions[]="'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value[prediction]) . "'";
}
$check="SELECT fullname FROM test_celebrities WHERE shortname IN (" . implode(',' $predictions) . ")";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    if (!$count++) {
         // this is the first row
    }
```

But note that you now have two sets of data which are sorted differently - hence you'll need to iterate through one and lookup values in the other.